# Accessing member of a C++ object allocated with malloc?

Tags: c++, malloc

[Editor's note: I have edited the title to try to make this useful to others in the future.  To give the answerers credit, this was just a "why does this not work?" question when they answered it!]

The following code crashes at the `top -> ...` line with a segmentation fault, regardless of what `Node*` is trying to be pushed onto the vector children. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

```
struct Node
{
    string data;
    struct Node* parent;
    vector<struct Node*> children;
};

struct Node* push(string word, struct Node* top)
{
    Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp -> data = word;
    temp -> parent = top;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Node* top = push("blah", NULL);
    Node* temp = NULL;
    top -> children.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `top` and is it pointing to something?

Comment: Please show a complete example where top is initialised.

Comment: You are allowed to push a NULL pointer into your vector, but your `top` needs to point to a valid memory region, else bad things happen.

Comment: And where is the `top` in your code except mentioned once in `main` even without declaration? Post some real code...

Comment: Unlike C, it's not required to type `struct` before `Node*` in C++. You can just type `Node*` and the compiler will know you're talking about the structure `Node`.

Comment: Apparently the compiler assumes something else, otherwise it wouldn't have crashed. What's your **real** code?

Comment: @In silico : I didn't know that, thank you.

I added an initialization for top as well as a "push" function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `malloc` will not call constructors.  And you're counting on the vector `children` to be constructed.

Replace:

```
Node* temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

With:

```
Node* temp = new Node;
```

*`malloc` (from C) and `new` (from C++) will both allocate the memory you need, but only `new` will call the required constructors, as C doesn't use them.  If you're not positive that you need malloc, use new.*

Comment: @vanchagreen: It sounds like you come from a C background. Note that C++ works very differently from C, to a point where they are practically considered to be very different languages. I recommend picking up [a C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You might not need to start with an intro book, but it certainly doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `malloc` on objects, you should use `new` instead. `malloc` is a C function that just allocates a chunk of memory, while the C++ operator `std::new` also takes care of the object initialization and construction - step that you've missed here and that causes you troubles (for example the constructor for `temp->children` has never been called in your case).

As a rule of thumb: if you're writing C++ code you should use the C++ operators `std::new` and `std::delete` for dynamic memory allocations and releases, not the C functions.

Comment: I downvoted you because I mistakenly thought you were wrong -- in large part because you didn't explain why they were different (in the initial version of the answer, which was just the first sentence).  Then I did a bit more looking around, and realized I was wrong and you were right, and cancelled the downvote -- although I didn't upvote because the initial version was still a poor answer.  Now that you've added a good clear explanation, I've upvoted.

Comment: There is no `std::new` or `std::delete`. `new` and `delete` aren't even functions (nor are the operators); they are language constructs.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `children` vector isn't correctly initialized. You should use `Node* temp = new Node;` instead of `malloc` to call the constructor for `Node`, which calls the constructor of `children`, thus correctly initializing the `vector`

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, it looks like you have come from C and are in need of [a good C++ book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) C++ is not just "C with `class`es"!

Your `push` function looks very much like it should be a *constructor*. A constructor is called by `new` after it has allocated the required memory and performs the necessary initialisation. The compiler will generate one for you, if you don't provide one (it will also provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator (see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

Since you called `malloc()` and not `new`, the synthesised default constructor was not called and therefore the `children` `vector` was not initialised, which caused your access violation.

Here I demonstrate how you may implement a default constructor (and disable the other two), to initiate each of the three data members of your `class` (or `struct`):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::string;

class Node
{
public:
    Node(const string& word, Node* top)
        :data(word)
        ,parent(top)
        ,children()
    {
        if (top != NULL)
        {
            top->children.push_back(this);
        }
    }

    virtual ~Node()
    {
        std::vector<Node*>::iterator i = std::find(children.begin(), children.end(), this);
        if (i != children.end())
        {
            parent->children.erase(i);
        }
        // TODO: You may wish to destory children at this point
    }

private:
    Node(const Node& disable);
    Node& operator =(const Node& disable);

private:
    string data;
    Node* parent;
    vector<Node*> children;
};

int main()
{
    Node top("blah", NULL);
    Node child("foo", &top);
}
```

I also implemented a *destructor*, which removes a node from its parent's children on destruction.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() just allocates an empty block of memory, you should use the new() operator which initializes all member objects;

```
Node* temp = new Node();
```