# Why would <list> element cause segmentation fault in an object using memory from malloc()

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this (simplified) C++ class:

```
class node{
public:
    int num;
    list<int> iplist;   
};
```

Then I dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
node* node1 = (node*) malloc( sizeof(node) );
```

It's OK to use `node1->num`, it's totally fine. However, `(node1->iplist).push_back(10)`will cause segementation fault. I changed it back to:

```
node* node1 = new node;
```

It works fine again including `(node1->iplist).push_back(10)`.
I've Google'd for the answer, realizing maybe this is because `malloc()` doesn't initialize the element. But, I'm still confused on how to initialize a `<list>` element when using `malloc()`.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't run constructors. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of using a block of uninitialized memory as if it were a valid, fully constructed `node` instance. Why exactly do you want to use `malloc` in the first place?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ code.

Comment: *"But I'm still confused that how to initialize a element if I used malloc"* You shouldn't do that, that's essentially what `new` is for. Modern C++ even bans the use of `new` in favour of `make_unique` and `make_shared`. If you have to separate memory allocation from initialization, you must use placement-new to call the constructors manually: `node* node1 = static_cast<node*>(malloc(sizeof(node))); new(static_cast<void*>(node1)) node();` (include `<memory>`).

Comment: On of the *many* duplicates on this question : ["Accessing member of a C++ object allocated with malloc?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774232/accessing-member-of-a-c-object-allocated-with-malloc)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Because I use C more than C++ so I just want to try it in C++ and then I run into this question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Maybe I should delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `malloc()` to allocate your object, the most reliable way is to overload the `new` operator for your object.

```
class node{
public:
    int num;
    std::list<int> iplist;

    void * operator new (size_t sz) { return malloc(sz); }
    void operator delete (void *p) { free(p); }
    void * operator new[] (size_t sz) { return malloc(sz); }
    void operator delete[] (void *p) { free(p); }
};
```

With these overloads, using `new` or `new[]` will result in a call to `malloc()` to get the memory for the dynamic allocation request. A call to `delete` and `delete[]` will use `free()` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: The reason this answer is more reliable than using placement `new` is that placement `new` requires you to explicitly call the destructor of the object before calling `free()`. This answer also still allows your object to be correctly managed by a smart pointer without requiring you to define a custom deleter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use malloc for c++ objects,
you have to use "placement new":

```
void *p = malloc( sizeof(node) );
node* node1 = new (p) node;
node1->iplist.push_back(10);
```